# TFS 2010 with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi I have downloaded TFS 2010 Trail version. And currently my system is having SQL Server 2005 installed. So I want to configure TFS2010 with SQL Server2005. But I could not able to give the SQL Server 2005 connection string, It is showing an error message that SQL Server 2005 can't be used with TFS2010. Please guide me that am I doing in correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately TFS 2010 requires SQL Server 2008.

Taken from the [installation guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24337):

> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server requires SQL Server 2008. You
>   have multiple options:
>
> - You can use the basic configuration of Team Foundation Server, which
>     comes with SQL Server Express.
> - You can install SQL Server 2008.
> - You can use an existing installation of SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the online ms documentation:
If you want to add Team Foundation Server 2010 (TFS) plugin, you must first install the provider which can be found here :
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6/view/Reviews

In other words this'll make tfs work with sqlserver2005.